# Can the H2 console be run on the Spring management port?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-actuator

Using Spring boot, with actuator and in-memory H2.

In application.properties, I currently have (irrelevant settings ignored):

```
server.port=8080
management.server.port=9090

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

which deploys the h2 console at http://localhost:8080/h2-console as expected.  From the docs, there doesn't appear to be an h2.console.use-management-port option or h2.console.port option.  Is it possible to get the h2 console to either

```
http://localhost:9090/h2-console
```

or (preferably)

```
http://localhost:9090/actuator/h2-console
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your issue, and found a possible solution.

Change `spring.h2.console.enabled` to `false` in `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8080
management.server.port=9090
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
```

Define `ServletConfigurer` and manually initialize H2 console in `onStartup`:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfigurer implements ServletContextInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    try {
      ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      Class<?> webServlet = Class.forName("org.h2.server.web.WebServlet", true, classLoader);
      Servlet servlet = (Servlet) webServlet.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

      ServletRegistration.Dynamic h2cs = servletContext.addServlet("h2-console", servlet);
      h2cs.addMapping("/actuator/h2-console/*");
      h2cs.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Including `managementPort` to tomcat for H2 console to run on:

```
@Value("${management.server.port:${server.port}}")
private String managementPort;

@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
  TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
  if (StringUtils.hasText(managementPort)) {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(Integer.valueOf(managementPort));
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
  }
  return tomcat;
}
```

Block `/actuator/**` from other ports with filter:

```
@Configuration
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/actuator/**" }, filterName = "actuatorFilter")
public class ActuatorFilter implements Filter {

  @Value("${management.server.port:${server.port}}")
  private Integer managementPort;

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain )throws IOException, ServletException {
    if(request.getLocalPort() == managementPort){
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
      ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(404);
    }
  }
}
```

I have not found a way to directly use the management port as Connector, in my view the latter part is more a work around than the perfect solution to your issue. I will try to find ways to improve the latter part of my answer, or maybe some other users can give more insights to it.

Hope it helps a bit :)

---

**EDIT:**

I found the `urlPatterns` in my `@WebFilter` does not work, and made some amendments:

`ActuatorFilter`:

```
@Component
public class ActuatorFilter implements Filter {

  @Value("${management.server.port:${server.port}}")
  private Integer managementPort;

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain )throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("req: " + request);
    if(request.getLocalPort() == managementPort){
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
      ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(404);
    }
  }
}
```

`FilterConf`:

```
@Component
public class FilterConf {

  @Autowired
  ActuatorFilter actuatorFilter;

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(actuatorFilter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/actuator/*");
    registration.setOrder(1);
    return registration;
  }

}
```

Comment: This helps somewhat, I'm deploying this behind a firewall, which forwards everything to 8080.  So 9090 is "safe", and we're using that for health checks and stuff with actuator.  I'd like to run the console behind the firewall, so with your workaround, I can put it on 9999 (or whatever).  being on the same port as the actuator is for convenience and ease of management.